# JAudioTagger and Android - Change a value in an mp3?

Tags: android, id3, jaudiotagger

I can read meta information like title, artist, album art and other information from audio files, but I have never been able to successfully write the meta information.

Any have any experiences with this? Are there better libraries than JAudioTagger?

I'd offer some example code, but I've tried a dozen things that didn't work.

Answer (score 10):

Something like

```
AudioFile audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(testFile);
Tag newTag = audioFile.getTag();
newTag.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM,"October");
newTag.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST,"U2");
audioFile.commit();
```

but if you are using android you also need to do

```
TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().setAndroid(true);
```

because of some bugs with android version of Java

Comment: is the library supported on android ? i read on many threads that writing metadata doesnt work on android ?

Comment: I think it should work as long as setAndroid() is set, but I haven't tried it, if it does not work please raise bugs on the issue tracker, there are not any currently.