# JaudioTagger doesn't acually change tag fields

Tags: java, android, mp3, id3

I'm building an application that edits tags on mp3 files using [JAudioTagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/). The only problem is that the mp3 file's fileds don't change when i open the file in [Google Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music) app.

```
            TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().setAndroid(true);
            File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("smoething"), songname + ".mp3");
            AudioFile audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(tempFile);
            Tag tag = audioFile.getTag();
            tag.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST, "artist"); // when i open music app the artist is "unknown"
            audioFile.setTag(tag); // even without this i'm getting the same result
            audioFile.commit();
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6667742/4369107) the code should be working fine but for some reason it doesn't. Does someone have a clue what i have done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

So i found out that the problem was with the method `commit()` (it just didn't worked) so i used `AudioFileIO.write(audioFile)` instead that does the same thing.